# Sparkstreaming + Kafka to hdfs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

When I try to consume the message from kafka topic using spark streaming getting the below error

```
scala> val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "<ipaddress>:2181","spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("test1" -> 5))
```

Error:

```
`missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'KafkaUtils.class'.
Could not access term kafka in package <root>,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'KafkaUtils.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of <root>.`
```

Scala version: 2.11.8
spark version: 2.1.0.2.6.0.3-8

I have used all kind of library for spark-streaming-kafka but nothing worked:

I am executing the code from the spark shell:

```
./spark-shell --jars /data/home/local/504/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10-1.5.1.jar, /data/home/local/504/spark-streaming_2.10-1.5.1.jar
```

Code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "<ipaddress>:2181","spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("test1" -> 5))
```

Any suggestion for this issue.

Comment: which version of kafka are you using ?

Comment: Curious, have you heard of Kafka Connect? There's an HDFS plugin for it that doesn't require you to write any code other than a property file

Comment: its kafka 0.10+

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Scala 2.11 and spark 2.1.0 you should be using these jars

- `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.0.jar`
- `spark-streaming_2.11-2.1.0.jar`

If you are using Kafka 0.10+ otherwise change it accordingly.

And the simple program would look like

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))

//Parameters for kafka
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "servers,
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "test-consumer-group",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)
val topics = "topics,seperated,by,comma".split(",")

// crate dstreams
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  streamingContext,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)

//stream.print()
stream.map(_.value().toString).print()
```

Hope this hepls!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, my kafka version is 0.10+.

Comment: But I am getting another error after adding the above jar files :

Comment: scala> import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
<console>:26: error: object kafka is not a member of package org.apache
       import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer